# Custom list of all paper in a .bib database

Tags: biblatex

I want to list all papers in a bib database. However, the code

`\nocite{*}`

`\printbibliography[sorting=chronological, type={article}, title={\quad}, heading=subbibliography]`

produces an extra line due to the `\quad`. What I want is a list of all papers **directly** under some text in the form of

- Paper 1

  author & journal info

  abstract
- Paper 2

  author & journal info

  abstract

...

Can anyone enlighten me about how to achieve this?

By the way, I used the code

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  $\bullet$ {\bodyfont \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    %\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}\itshape%
    \usebibmacro{journal}%
    , vol. \textbf{\printfield{volume}},
   \setunit{\space}%
    \printfield{pages}%
    \newunit%
    %\printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit{\space}%
    \printtext[parens]{\printfield{year}}%
    %\newunit%
  }}
\par
\newblock%
{
\quad\usebibmacro{abstract}
}
  \par\vspace{1\baselineskip}
}
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  %\small\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}%
  \ifblank{#3}{}{#3\space}#1%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
    {\addcomma\space}
    {}%
}


\newcommand{\printbibsection}[1]{
  \begin{refsection}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[sorting=chronological, type={#1}, title={\quad}, heading=subbibliography]
  \end{refsection}
}

\DeclareSortingScheme{chronological}{
  \sort[direction=descending]{\field{year}}
  \sort[direction=descending]{\field{month}}
}
```

Comment: Does `heading=none` (instead of `heading=subbibliography`) help? You should use `\defbibenvironment{bibliography}{\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}{\item}` instead of manually inserting bullets via a redefinition of the driver. Use `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}` instead of your redefinition of `\DeclareNameFormat{author}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get rid of the title/heading of the bibliography, use `heading=none`.

You can make `biblatex` print the bibliography as an `itemize`d list, just add

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\begin{itemize}}
  {\end{itemize}}
  {\item}
```

to your preamble. (No need to manually insert bullet points etc.)

I would refrain from defining a `\DeclareNameFormat{author}`, just use `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}`.

To achieve the layout for articles you are looking for, I would suggest modifying the standard `article` driver (see MWE below) only where necessary.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,backend=biber,maxnames=999]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{testart,
  author        = {Arnold Uthor and William Riter},
  title         = {A Very Interesting Article},
  journal       = {Journal of Articles},
  volume        = {7},
  number        = {3},
  pages         = {1-5},
  date          = {2010},
  abstract      = {Abstract of a paper. Blah Blah Bla. Omnes Gallia est divisa in partes tres. This text needs to be longer. Ideally, it should be in English, so the hyphenation algorithm can do its thing.},
  issn          = {1234-5678},
}
@article{testartlong,
  author        = {Arnold Uthor and William Riter and Rita Esearcher and Steven C. Ientist and Stuart T. Udent and Peter R. Ofessor and Lewis E. C. Turer},
  title         = {A Very Interesting Article With a Lot of Authors},
  journal       = {Journal of Articles},
  volume        = {5},
  number        = {8},
  pages         = {8-12},
  date          = {2012},
  abstract      = {This is a fake asbtract of a non-existing paper, but it should still contain quite some text, so I will cotinue to make something up. This is lorem ipsum dolor sit amet bla blah blih blud.},
  doi           = {12345/6789.10},
}
@article{testarto,
  author        = {Walter Ordsmith},
  journaltitle  = {Journal of Sciences and Stuff},
  volume        = {42},
  title         = {The Work},
  subtitle      = {Subtitle},
  date          = {1983},
  abstract      = {I am really not confident that I can make up another (third!) fake abstract of somekind of paper that is long enough to leave the impression it actually is a proper abstract.},
  url           = {http://www.example.com},
}
@book{testbook,
  author        = {Arnold Uthor},
  title         = {A Book},
  subtitle      = {Some Books Have Subtitles},
  date          = {2013},
  publisher     = {Peter Ublisher \& Co.},
  location      = {Place City},
}
@book{testbooko,
  author        = {Walter Ordsmith},
  title         = {Title},
  subtitle      = {Subtitle},
  date          = {2011},
  publisher     = {Books},
  location      = {Atlantis},
  editor        = {Edward Ditor},
}
\end{filecontents}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\begin{itemize}}
  {\end{itemize}}
  {\item}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \printtext{\smallskip\newline}% you can choose between \smallskip, \medskip, \bigskip, or no skip at all
  %\bibstring{byauthor}\setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printunit{\newline}%<--- comment this for no newline before journal
  %\newunit\newblock% <-- uncomment this for no newline before journal stuff
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \iffieldundef{abstract}
    {}%
    {\setunit{\smallskip\newline}%
     \bibcpstring[\textbf]{abstract}%
     \setunit{\newline}%
     \printfield{abstract}}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \printtext{\smallskip\newline}% you can choose between \smallskip, \medskip, \bigskip, or no skip at all
  %\bibstring{byauthor}\setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printtext{\newline}%<--- comment this for no newline
  %\newunit\newblock% <-- uncomment this for no newline
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \iffieldundef{abstract}
    {}%
    {\setunit{\smallskip\newline}%
     \bibcpstring[\textbf]{abstract}%
     \setunit{\newline}%
     \printfield{abstract}}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\newcommand{\printbibsection}[1]{
  \begin{refsection}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[sorting=chronological, type={#1}, title={\quad}, heading=none]
  \end{refsection}
}

\DeclareSortingScheme{chronological}{
  \sort[direction=descending]{\field{year}}
  \sort[direction=descending]{\field{month}}
  \sort[direction=descending]{\field{day}}
}
\begin{document}
  Hi, this should be a lorem ipsum text, but I can't be bothered to load it, so you will have to deal with this.
  \printbibsection{article}
  And now, over to the books!
  \printbibsection{book}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for the MWE.